# Nginx stub status global or per server block?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

I want to enable the http_stub_status module in nginx.
I have multiple server {} blocks in my nginx.conf, for different applications.

What it is not clear to me from the nginx documentation is are these metrics from the module global per nginx instance or are they per server block?
Do I have to configure the location for each server block?

Comment: These are service wide statistics, for example "idle client connections waiting for a request" cannot be associated with a specific `server` block. So you only need one stub status to obtain the full picture.